# problem in jquery to when use portfolio this() statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey, i have problem on my site.
semangart.com.

go to portfolio page.
when your pointer go one of my page is show effect fadeTo right,

now the problem begin:

1. When your pointer move to first img then go to next img(do it with fast), the animation with repeatedly show, are have suggestion? to fix it.
2. My jquery Script is to long. n not dinamic, i wanted to this but i dont know how to write it. this is my script.

---

```
//portfolio
//1
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".1p").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".1pF").fadeTo("slow",1);
    $(".1i").fadeTo("slow",0.3);
  });
  $(".1p").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".1pF").fadeTo("slow",0);
    $(".1i").fadeTo("slow",1);
  });
});
//2
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".2p").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".2pF").fadeTo("slow",1);
    $(".2i").fadeTo("slow",0.3);
  });
  $(".2p").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".2pF").fadeTo("slow",0);
    $(".2i").fadeTo("slow",1);
  });
});
```

Comment: What does the question have to do with `this()`?

Comment: so what the legal class, i studied it by myself.